# Open VPN Cant Connect RDP

Tags: networking, windows-10, wireless-networking, remote-desktop, openvpn

I'Am not able to connect rdp over OPEN VPN with WiFi Router but Vpn Connected successfully.And the connection is success without the wifi router (Connected directly from ISP Modem)

here is the error message getting while i, connecting with WiFi Router
**Router Model Is : D-Link  DIR-600M**

Anything i need to setip in the router?. My knowledge is zero in this

Sun Apr 19 17:41:29 2020 AEAD Decrypt error: bad packet ID (may be a replay): [ #15858 ] -- see the man page entry for --no-replay and --replay-window for more info or silence this warning with --mute-replay-warnings
Sun Apr 19 17:41:29 2020 AEAD Decrypt error: bad packet ID (may be a replay): [ #15860 ] -- see the man page entry for --no-replay and --replay-window for more info or silence this warning with --mute-replay-warnings
Sun Apr 19 17:41:29 2020 AEAD Decrypt error: bad packet ID (may be a replay): [ #15862 ] -- see the man page entry for --no-replay and --replay-window for more info or silence this warning with --mute-replay-warnings
Sun Apr 19 17:41:29 2020 AEAD Decrypt error: bad packet ID (may be a replay): [ #15864 ] -- see the man page entry for --no-replay and --replay-window for more info or silence this warning with --mute-replay-warnings
Sun Apr 19 17:41:29 2020 AEAD Decrypt error: bad packet ID (may be a replay): [ #15866 ] -- see the man page entry for --no-replay and --replay-window for more info or silence this warning with --mute-replay-warnings
Sun Apr 19 17:41:29 2020 AEAD Decrypt error: bad packet ID (may be a replay): [ #15868 ] -- see the man page entry for --no-replay and --replay-window for more info or silence this warning with --mute-replay-warnings
Sun Apr 19 17:41:29 2020 AEAD Decrypt error: bad packet ID (may be a replay): [ #15870 ] -- see the man page entry for --no-replay and --replay-window for more info or silence this warning with --mute-replay-warnings

Comment: Make sure the subnets at each are different (you can connect but not pass traffic if they are the same). Make sure your subnet mask at each end contains the entire subnet (e.g. mask = 255.255.255.0 , not 255.255.255.255 .

Comment: Yes, The subnet mask is used  255.255.255.0

Comment: Can you RDP by IP address?

Comment: Yes, I can connect some times but it will disconnect frequently, and very slower

Comment: Try  updating the firmware in your router

Comment: it's already :(

Comment: I would look to some kind of networking deficiency. Software errors or mis- configuration would more likely prevent connection.

Comment: mis-configuration? i dont know about that